# physics type to No collision using python

Tags: python, game-engine, physics

How to set the physics type to No collision in bge using python?

I need a script to change the physics type to No_collision in game, please help me

Answer (score 1):

You can't change the physics type.

You can replace the object with another one, that is of the desired physics type. *Do not forget to copy all necessary attributes from the previous object (such as linear and angular velocity).*

Answer (score 0):

hmm try using

```
cont = bge.logic.getCurrentController() 
obj = cont.owner
obj.suspendDynamics()
```

if it doesn't fit your needs you will have to replace the object by another one which has the collision type you want in-game.

Comment: Yvain, this script just stops dynamics, but does not change its type to No_collision :(